# Using Load Balancers To Terminate TLS For TCP/IP Connections

Tags: ssl, nginx, tcp, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I am writing a TCP/IP server that handlers persistent connections. I'll be using TLS to secure the communication and have a question about how to do this:

Currently I have a load balancer (AWS ELB) in front of a single server. In order for the load balancer to do the TLS termination for the duration of the connection it must hold on to the connection and forward the plain text to the application behind it.

```
client ---tls---> Load Balancer ---plain text---> App Server
```

This works great. Yay! My concern is that I'll need a load balancer in front of every app server because, presumably, the number of connections the load balancer can handle is the same as the number of connections the app server can handle (assuming the same OS and NIC). This means that if I had 1 load balancer and 2 app servers, I could wind up in a situation where the load balancer is at full capacity and each app server is at half capacity. In order to avoid this problem I'd have to create a 1 to 1 relationship between the load balancers and app servers.

I'd prefer the app server to not have to do the TLS termination because, well, why recreate the wheel? Are there better methods than to have a 1 to 1 relationship between the load balancer and the app server to avoid the capacity issue mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two probable flaws in your presumption.

The first is the assumption that your application server will experience the same amount of load for a given number of connections as the load balancer.   Unless your application server is extremely well-written, it seems reasonable that it would run out of CPU or memory or encounter other scaling issues before it reached the theoretical maximum ~64K concurrent connections IPv4 can handle on a given IP address.  If that's really true, then great -- well done.

The second issue is that a single load balancer from ELB is *not* necessarily a single machine.  A single ELB launches a hidden virtual machine in each availability zone where you've attached the ELB to a subnet, regardless of the number of instances attached, and the number of ELB nodes scales up automatically as load increases.  (If I remember right, I've seen as many as nodes 8 running at the same time -- for a *single* ELB.) Presumably the class of those ELB instances could change , too, but that's not a facet that's well documented. There's not a charge for these machines, as they are included in the ELB price, so as they scale up, the monthly cost for the ELB doesn't change... but provisioning qty = 1 ELB does not mean you get only 1 ELB node.

Comment: Thank you for this. Very helpful!